# How do we plot a red dot (to represent a trade) on a financial candlestick chart?

Tags: matlab, plot

I am plotting a financial candlestick chart using this MATLAB function:

http://www.mathworks.com/help/toolbox/finance/candlefts.html

How do I plot a red dot on the chart, to represent a trade at that point?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

For the point you want to add, you would need its position on the y-axis `yValue` and the date where it is to be placed on the x-axis `xValue` (formatted as a single [serial date number](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/datenum.html)). Then the following should work:

```
candle(...);  %# Make your candle plot
hold on;      %# Add to the existing plot
plot(xValue,yValue,'r.');  %# Plot a red dot
```

If you want a larger red dot, you can replace the last line with either of the following:

```
plot(xValue,yValue,'r.','MarkerSize',20);
plot(xValue,yValue,'ro','MarkerFaceColor','r');
```